# How to match the '"\"' pattern enclosed in single quotes at the beginning of the row using sed

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

How to match the "\" pattern at the beginning of each row in a file using `sed`.

Comment: For questions like these, you need to provide us your sample text (and) what did you try (and) what problems were you unable to overcome?

Comment: I will add it in the question

Comment: Provide a verifiable sample input and an expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to substitute it with

`sed s/^["\"]\/<your replacement>/`

Comment: I want to replace double quotes, forward slash and double quotes at the begining of each row. the command that you gave doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Escape your forward slash or quotes with another f. slash : if you want to replace every "\" by "^" in a file containing the following text : `This \is \a \test`, use :

```
sed 's|\\|^|g' file
```

With 's' meaning 'substitute', '|' as separators, and 'g' meaning 'global'.

It will output `This ^is ^a ^test`